# Position on a path

Tags: geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, polygons

So the situation is: I have a path (which is represented as a two-dimensional array of GPS coordinates) and I have a percentage position on this path.

I.e. I know that a person has walked 80% of the path (which is for example an array like this [[1,1], [5,5], [9,9]]). What are coordinates of our stranger?

Comment: Do you know how to compute the distance between two points given in GPS coordinates? Add all of them up to get the total distance. Then see how many you have to add up to get $80\%$ of that distance.